# Uso e significato di "uscirsene"

Tags: verbs, meaning, pronouns

In un dialogo che appare in un libro d'italiano per studenti stranieri ho trovato la frase seguente:

> Va be’, comunque… è la direttrice, uno lo sa che lei **se
>   n’esce** in questo modo…

Il dialogo è tra due colleghi di lavoro e fa riferimento alla loro direttrice, che spesso parla usando le parolacce.

Nel [dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/uscirsene) ho trovato che "uscirsene" vuol dire

> saltare fuori.

Tuttavia, mi piacerebbe avere una spiegazione un po' più dettagliata sul significato di questa espressione e alcuni esempi di uso. Me li potreste fare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In italiano esistono moltissimi verbi che, uniti a particelle
> pronominali o riflessive, subiscono un cambiamento di significato, a
> volte minimo, in altri casi molto diverso.
>
> Questi verbi sono molto usati nelle espressioni idiomatiche.

Nel contesto da te citato ***uscirsene*** indica dire qualcosa in modo improvviso, inaspettato, senza alcun annuncio.

Ad esempio:

> **Uscirsene** con una battuta: dare una risposta scherzosa, o imprevista, ed elusiva;
>
> All’improvviso **se n’è uscito** con un’idea geniale

In [questo interessante blog sui verbi pronominali](http://www.easitalian.com/blog/2015/10/04/i-verbi-pronominali/) puoi trovare un sacco di esempi e casistiche.

Answer (score 3):

Prendo dalla definizione di "Uscire" sul dizionario del Corriere:

http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/U/uscire.shtml

> 4 fig. Sbottare, dire all'improvviso qlco. di inaspettato: u. in improperi; anche con arg. espresso da frase (introd. da a): u. a dire un'assurdità; freq. nella forma ***uscirsene*** con qlco., nel sign. di esprimere, dire qlco. di inaspettato o che non andava detto: se ne uscì con una delle sue trovate